# Product commenting system

Tags: product

Can you guys suggest me any good FREE product review system? The functionality should include commenting on the reviews by customers, Something like 'Disqus'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any free ones, however this appears to be a decently priced extension at 9.99EU:
http://shop.tentura.eu/magento-extensions/disqus-for-magento.html

It implements Disqus into Magento, providing the exact functionality you're looking for.

Also, it appears they've released a "light" version of this plugin for free as well:
https://github.com/involic/Magento-DISQUS-Comments-Integration-Light

Seems a little out dated, but may still work.

Answer (score 2):

[Yotpo](https://www.yotpo.com/) is a startup that seems to be picking up some steam - they've been at a few Magento conferences.

Having demoed their platform I think [it provides the functionality you're looking for](https://www.yotpo.com/features). The plugin is free; the SaaS solution is free up to a certain number of visitors monthly. So **this may cost you money in the end** if you have a **large amount of traffic**.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yopto-reviews-5759.html